# notifyDataChanged grid view without data changed android

Tags: android

I want to trigger the `notifyDataChanged` of my custom `GridView` `adapter`without any changing in my data just to `color` item in the grid every time I want and without any click on the items, like timer will trigger this action and do what should I need

I tried the re-create the adapter but its not working

Comment: Do you have bean class with you

Comment: use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` method when the timer or whatever code of your fires

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); don't work cuz the data didn't changed @SatyenUdeshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after the

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

did you once again set this adapter to `GridView` ? if not then write

```
yourGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

after 
`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: should I create new adapter ? or the same old one is good ? I did clear for the adapter and re-fill it but its not working @Satyen

Comment: no need to create new adapter old one is good if possible do post your code here so we can get a better idea

Comment: `customGridAdapter.clear();
  customGridAdapter.setNewPosition(nextPos);
   customGridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   customGridAdapter.addAll(gridArray);
   gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);`

Comment: the problem was from the `AsyncTask` and I used `runOnUiThread` and every thing is going good